# Getting consistent tick lengths and positions of labels

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, ticks

**Bug introduced in 7 or earlier and persists through 11.0.1 or later. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

I'm trying to have identical *tick mark lengths* for both horizontal and vertical ticks and I wish them to look outside of the plot area. But at the final plot tick mark labels overlap with tick marks:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0, {0, .015}}, {Pi, 180, {0, .015}}, {2 Pi, 360, {0, .015}}, {3 Pi, 
     540, {0, .015}}}, {{0, 0, {0, .015}}}}, ImageSize -> {1000, 200}, AspectRatio -> 1/6]
```

> [image: plot]

**Is it possible to position tick mark labels correctly?**

Answer (score 6):

**Diagnosis**

It appears that MMA misplaces tick labels when the ticks are long and the `AspectRatio` is different from 1.

If you set the `AspectRatio` to 1 and use the same values for the horizontal and vertical tick lengths, the appearance looks fine.

```
ts = .1;
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0, {0, ts}}, {Pi, 180, {0, ts}}, {2 Pi, 
 360, {0, ts}}, {3 Pi, 540, {0, ts}}}, {{0, 0, {0, ts}}}}]
```

[image: ticks 1]

Now let's set the `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` and see what happens:

[image: ticks2]

The vertical and horizontal ticks appear to be of the same length. However, the horizontal labels are positioned over the end of the respective ticks.

---

**Possible Workaround**

Now, if you use "aesthetically appealing" tick lengths, `ts = .025`, the problem fails to show up, as far as I can tell.

[image: ticks 3]

I'm not sure what you might do to get the tick labels properly placed if you want really long ticks.  Playing with `ImagePadding` does not help.

---

Btw, I  interpret the documentation's statement, "Tick mark lengths are given as a fraction of the distance across the whole plot." as meaning that the **plot width** is used for determining the size of the tick lengths (both horizontal and vertical) when they are manually set. **So the `AspectRatio` does not appear to influence tick lengths**.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't know how the problem come from, but I finally fix it with a small trick and wait for others to solve it completely.

The ticks label only react to the longest tick when AspectRatio applied to the plot. So here I add one tick with the same mode but a longer length `{2.3 \[Pi], 80, {0, 0.6}}}`:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0, {0, .1 }}, {Pi, 180, {0, .1 }}, {2 Pi, 
     360, {0, .1 }}, {3 Pi, 540, {0, .1 }}, {2.3 \[Pi], 
     80, {0, 0.2}}}, {{0, 0, {0, .1}}}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

And the result:

[image]

Then just make the extra tick fade away, of course you can change the length of extra one to make your plot look pretty:

```
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0, {0, .2 GoldenRatio}}, {Pi, 
     180, {0, .2 GoldenRatio}}, {2 Pi, 
     360, {0, .2 GoldenRatio}}, {3 Pi, 
     540, {0, .2 GoldenRatio}}, {2.3 \[Pi], , {0, 0.52}, 
     Transparent}}, {{0, 0, {0, .2}}}}]
```

And the result:

[image]